# For two commutative elements a,b of a finite order in a group G, why does there exist an order of order $LCM[|a|,|b|]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

This is Q.43 of Chapter 4(Cyclic Groups) in Joseph A. Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

I haven't been able to prove it myself but I also believe Gallian's solution is incorrect.

Joseph A. Gallian offered a proof as follows -

> Let $|a|=m,|b|=b \ and \ gcd(m,n) = d$ Then $LCM[m,n] = \frac {mn}{d}, \ |{a}^d| = \frac {m}{d}, \ and \ |b| = n$ then by exercise 41 $|{a}^db| = LCM[m,n]$

Also, what we proved in exercise 41 was this -

> $For \ a \ group \ G, \ a,b \in G$ such that $<a>\cap <b> = {e}$ where $e$ is the identity element of the group, then $|ab| = l.c.m[|a|,|b|]$

However, the Claim Gallian has used is certainly NOT true. We look at $G =\Bbb Z_{84}$
$$6,7 \in G$$
$$g.c.d(|6|,|7|) = g.c.d(14,12)= 2$$
Here, raising an element to the power of 2 would mean operating it with itself twice so if I am raising 7 to the power of 2 I just need to find $$2*7(mod 84)$$ which is 14.

However, the result doesn't hold at all because $$|14+6|=|20|=21$$ while it supposed to be $$L.C.M[|6|,|7|]=L.C.M[14,12] \ne 1$$

Have I actually found an error in Gallian?(No arrogance intended)

Edit : - I had accidentaly multiplied the elements in the add where I was supposed to add them. $$|14*6|=1|$$ has been changed to $$|14+6|=21$$

Comment: You'd take $14 + 6$, not $14\cdot 6$. But indeed, the argument as written is incorrect, one would need $\gcd\bigl(\frac{m}{d},n\bigr) = 1$, and that's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I am sorry, I fixed the error I made. I had written it correctly in my note-book and it still works in contradicting Gallian's proof. Are you saying that the result in itself is incorrect?

Edit : - By the way, I understand what you are saying. I thought Gallian had made the exact same error.

Comment: No, the result is correct (see below for a sketch of the correct argument), only the given argument isn't correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the argument you quoted is incorrect, for $d = \gcd(m,n)$, it does not follow that $\gcd\bigl(\frac{m}{d},n\bigr) = 1$. And we can't even heal it by instead taking $m$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ in case $\gcd\bigl(\frac{m}{d},n\bigr) > 1$, for an example consider $m = 12,\, n = 18$, then $\gcd\bigl(\frac{12}{6}, 18\bigr) = 2 > 1$ and $\gcd\bigl(12,\frac{18}{6}\bigr) = 3 > 1$.

Writing $m = d\mu$ and $n = d\nu$ with $\gcd(\mu,\nu) = 1$, we must split $d$ into two coprime factors $d_1,d_2$ such that $\gcd(d_1,\mu) = 1 = \gcd(d_2,\nu)$ and then look at $\frac{m}{d_1} = d_2\mu$ and $\frac{n}{d_2} = d_1\nu$. With such a factorisation, the order of $a^{d_1}b^{d_2}$ is $d_2\mu\cdot d_1\nu = \frac{mn}{d} = \operatorname{lcm}(m,n)$ since $\gcd(d_2\mu,d_1\nu) = 1$.